# Raspberry Pi Flurry Screensaver

Tags: macos, screen-saver

I have a Raspberry Pi that I am modding to put in a gutted [iMac G4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_G4). I want it to look as authentic as possible. Has anyone ported the [Flurry screensaver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxJhrLADNiU) to the Pi? I did a Google search but didn't find anything.

Does anyone know of anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install xscreensaver and xscreensaver-gl-extra which includes the 'flurry' screensaver:

```
sudo apt install xscreensaver
sudo apt install xscreensaver-gl-extra
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This is great! Thank you.